# Librosa on Python MacOS

Tags: python, module, spyder

I install librosa module for Python. My os is MacOS at terminal my Python is 3.10.12 but at spyder which is my IDE python is a 3.9 and I can't use librosa module, Python says there's no module with this name. What can I do?

I changed the env from 3.9 for 3.10.12 at spyder and now spyder doesn't work:

> "Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.1.0 and < 2.2.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you."

Comment: How did you install Spyder and how did you 'change the env from 3.9 for 3.10.12 at spyder' ? Are you using `conda` to manage environments?